# How should one delete all of the table (but not the table itself) without making the thread using that database give an error

Tags: android, sql

I'm trying to have a menu button to clear my database when it is pressed.  That works well as far as I can tell. However, as soon as new information is sent to the database, the app force closes. How should I stop this? 
Here is the clear part:

```
@Override 
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
//reset just makes all the variables in the thread reinitialize at base values
            mLemonadeMainMenuView.reset(); 
            NotesMade = 0;
            mDbHelper.deleteAllNotes();
            return true;
    }
```

Here is deleteallnotes():

```
public boolean deleteAllNotes() { return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"1", null) > 0; }
```

Here is the new data information:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mDbHelper.createNote(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1);
        NotesMade ++;
        mLemonadeMainMenuView.setCoords(NotesMade);
        return true;
    }
```

Finally, here is the receiving end:

```
         while(mNotesMade>mNoteId)
            {mNoteId++;
             Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mNoteId);
             Float x;
             Float y;
             Float size;
             x = Float.valueOf(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_X)));
             y= Float.valueOf(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_Y)));
             size =Float.valueOf(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_X)));
      canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 1, paint);}
}
```

*Note*: I have already tried starting and stopping the thread in addition to the above.

```
Logcat:12-30 11:51:29.812: E/AndroidRuntime(6311): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
12-30 11:51:29.812: E/AndroidRuntime(6311): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
12-30 11:51:29.812: E/AndroidRuntime(6311):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
12-30 11:51:29.812: E/AndroidRuntime(6311):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
12-30 11:51:29.812: E/AndroidRuntime(6311):     at com.drawing.LemonadeMainMenuView$LemonadeMainMenuThread.doDraw(LemonadeMainMenuView.java:75)
12-30 11:51:29.812: E/AndroidRuntime(6311):     at com.drawing.LemonadeMainMenuView$LemonadeMainMenuThread.run(LemonadeMainMenuView.java:52)
```

**Edit**: solved - see Community Wiki answer.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace (from the Logcat output) when the app force closes? That would help figure us out the problem.

Comment: Show the mDbHelper.deleteAllNotes(), please

Comment: How would i post the logcat trace?

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas? Jonathon Leffler was helpful but I still cant solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, you arrange to execute:

```
 DELETE FROM YourTable;
```

or:

```
 DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE 1=1;  -- If your DBMS does not like unconstrained deletes
```

or:

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE YourTable;
```

On the face of it, the `mDb.delete()` method drops the table rather than deleting the data from the table.  There's a reason why SQL uses CREATE and DROP separately from INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I changed it to this:     public boolean deleteAllNotes() {

      mDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM notes");
 return false;
    } with the same issue

Comment: Why return `false`?  Does that indicate non-failure (aka success)?

Comment: As far as I can tell in my program it shouldn't matter as I'm just running it, I will try returning true though. No luck in returning true either.

Comment: If the return value doesn't matter, then the function should be `void` so no-one has to check the return value that doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Same with void and no return statement.

Comment: added logcat if that will help

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a solution for anyone else who needs it, the method for deleteallnotes()  is:        public void deleteAllNotes() { mDb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");mDb.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); } This should drop and recreate the database.